# How to avoid adding duplicate records in the database with Entity Framework Code First and Web API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

My web application is built with MVC and Entity Framework Code First. To explain my question, I'm describing it with a simplified Album - Song example:

```
public abstract class MusicStoreEntity
{
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false), Key, Required, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

[Table(TableName), DataContract]
public class Album : MusicStoreEntity
{
    public const string TableName = "Albums";

    public virtual Collection<AlbumSong> Songs { get; set; }
}

[Table(TableName), DataContract]
public class Song : MusicStoreEntity
{
    public const string TableName = "Songs";

    public virtual Collection<AlbumSong> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

The two entities are connected many-to-many with a separate entity that contains two foreign keys, as well as an unique identifier:

```
[Table(TableName), DataContract]
public class AlbumSong : MusicStoreEntity
{
    public const string TableName = "AlbumSongs";

    [DataMember, Required]
    public Guid AlbumId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Required]
    public Guid SongId { get; set; }

    public virtual Song Song { get; set; }
}
```

With an incoming API call, you can create a new entity if the two entities aren't connected yet:

```
public void SetAlbumSong(Guid albumId, Guid songId) {
    var albumSong = DBContext.Set<AlbumSong>().SingleOrDefault(a => a.AlbumId == albumId && a.SongId == songId);
    if(albumSong == null) {
        var albumSong = new AlbumSong {
            AlbumId = albumId,
            SongId = songId
        }

        DBContext.Set<AlbumSong>().Add(albumSong);
        DBContext.SaveChanges();
    } else {
        // update existing albumSong
    }
}
```

But, when two API calls come in at approximately the same time with the same entity id's, there is a window that enables adding two AlbumSong entities between the same album and song.

One solution is making a [Composite Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Composite) that consists of both foreign id's in the AlbumSong entity. This way no two duplicate AlbumSongs can be made and an exception will be thrown.
A similar solution is adding an extra property to AlbumSong that combines the two id's and requiring the column to be unique.

However, I wondered if there are other (better, cleaner) solutions to this problem, as above solutions bring unwanted changes for my specific application.

(My web application is built with MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5.)

Comment: If you have a composite-key on this entity....if another table has a FK to this table, you'll have to bring both columns.  Which is why I tend to go with a unique constraint over a composite key.

Comment: Better, cleaner... This is highly opinion-based. I would go for the unique index and a singular primary key, if a compound key poses problems for your current application.

Answer (score 0):

A composite key is a good idea, and can be viewed as better database design, because the AlbumID and SongID are what truly identify the record as unique.

EF provides concurrency checking, and wouldn't require many changes other than updating your model and adding a try/catch to your else statement.  [This article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) can take you through the process, but will add a field to your database.  [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399228(v=vs.100).aspx) uses concurrency checking, but does not add a field to the database.